# Multiple Directions, Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am fairly new with JavaScript and Google Maps API.

I am trying to have my map display the directions on the map via polyline on any location I click on.

I have the code set up to my database and it displays multiple markers, however I can't seem to figure out how to make it show the directions through a polyline on a click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + MySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAnfs7bKE82qgb3Zc2YyS-oBT2yXp_ZAY8_ufC3CFXhHIE1NvwkxSySz_REpPq-4WZA27OwgbtyR3VcA"
            type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map;
    var geocoder;

    function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
       // map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40, -100), 4);
      }
    }

   function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById('addressInput').value;
     geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(latlng) {
       if (!latlng) {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       } else {
         searchLocationsNear(latlng);
       }
     });
   }

   function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
     GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = GXml.parse(data);
       var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
       map.clearOverlays();

       var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
       sidebar.innerHTML = '';
       if (markers.length == 0) {
         sidebar.innerHTML = 'No results found.';
         map.setCenter(new GLatLng(40, -100), 4);

       }

       var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
         var name = markers[i].getAttribute('name');
         var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
         var distance = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('distance'));
         var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lat')),
                                 parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lng')));

         var marker = createMarker(point, name, address);
         map.addOverlay(marker);
         var sidebarEntry = createSidebarEntry(marker, name, address, distance);
         sidebar.appendChild(sidebarEntry);
         bounds.extend(point);
       }
       map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
     });
   }

    function createMarker(point, name, address) {
      var marker = new GMarker(point);
      var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> <br/>' + address;
      GEvent.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
      });
      return marker;
    }

    function createSidebarEntry(marker, name, address, distance) {
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      var html = '<b>' + name + '</b> (' + distance.toFixed(1) + ')<br/>' + address;
      div.innerHTML = html;
      div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      div.style.marginBottom = '5px'; 
      GEvent.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
        GEvent.trigger(marker, 'click');
      });
      GEvent.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function() {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
      });
      GEvent.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function() {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
      });
      return div;
    }
     function showAddress(address) {
      if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(
          address,
          function(point) {
            if (!point) {
              alert(address + " not found");
            } else {
              map.setCenter(point, 15);
              var marker = new GMarker(point, {draggable: false});
              map.addOverlay(marker);
              GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.getLatLng().toUrlValue(6));
              });
              GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
//                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(marker.getLatLng().toUrlValue(6));
              });
          GEvent.trigger(marker, "click");
            }
          }
        );
      }

   }

    //]]>

  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
 <form action="#" onsubmit="searchLocations();">4
    //<form action="#" onsubmit="showAddress(this.address.value);searchLocations();">

    Address: <input type="text" id="addressInput" style="width:350px" name="address" value="323 East 75th Street, NY"/>

    Radius: <select id="radiusSelect">

      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="25">25</option>

    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Search Locations"/>

    <br/>    
    <br/>
<div style="width:600px; font-family:Arial, 
sans-serif; font-size:11px; border:1px solid black">
  <table> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr id="cm_mapTR">

        <td width="200" valign="top"> <div id="sidebar" style="overflow: auto; height: 400px; font-size: 11px; color: #000"></div>

        </td>
        <td> <div id="map" style="overflow: hidden; width:400px; height:400px"></div> </td>

      </tr> 
    </form>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So most importantly, you're using the Google Maps API V2, which is deprecated. You could be using V3, and here's where it documents the directions service: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/directions.html